# Wpf Binding two variables to Margin

Tags: wpf

I have two distinct properties of a component that should be used for the Margin property of another component. One will be for left / rigth and the other for top / bottom. Is it possible make the binding of two variables for a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your situation but some **converter** will be needed.

**1)** If you are in the simplest case then "simply" use a `MultiBinding` with an `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
<Window x:Class="MarginsBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MarginsBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Slider x:Name="horizontal"
                Maximum="1000"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Slider>
        <Slider x:Name="vertical"
                Maximum="1000"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Slider>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle.Margin>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <local:MarginConverter></local:MarginConverter>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding ElementName="horizontal" Path="Value"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="vertical" Path="Value"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Margin>
        </Rectangle>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MarginsBinding
{
    public class MarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Thickness margin = new Thickness
            {
                Left = (double)values[0],
                Right = (double)values[0],
                Top = (double)values[1],
                Bottom = (double)values[1]
            };

            return margin;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** If you have more advanced needs you can check another converter I've built here:

[**control margin properties depending on another control margin properties in wpf**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290172/control-margin-properties-depending-on-another-control-margin-properties-in-wpf)