# WPF application is not updating its Window.Left property at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get my wpf application to take up my right-side monitor when it loads. My approach involves me creating a property that stores the screen width value (as a double) and then bind this to the Window.Left property. But no matter what I do the application window doesn't move to my right monitor.

here is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.FooView"
        .. declarations
        Title="{Binding Title}" 
    Left="{Binding ScreenOffset, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Height="800"
    Width="1920"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

in my View Model:

```
    public double ScreenOffset
    {
        get
        {
            return _screenOffset;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_screenOffset != value)
            {
                _screenOffset = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ScreenOffset));
            }
        }
    }
    private double _screenOffset = 0.0;

    public FooViewModel()
    {
        ScreenOffset = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width + defaultOffset; 
        //Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = 1920
        //defaultOffset = 10.0
    }
```

My data binding works with other controls in my application. The only binding that doesn't seem to work is just the Left property. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with `Mode=TwoWay` binding? Also, what is the state of window?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the window state is set to Maximized and I have tried mode=twoWay. But the window stays the same

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to put the following code in your view model:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public double ScreenOffset
    {
        get
        {
            return _screenOffset;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_screenOffset != value)
            {
                _screenOffset = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I want to thank @PavelAnikhouski and @Miguel Carreira for your time and effort to help me figure this out. So, my problem had nothing to do with the fact that I wasn't setting up my binding properly. My issue was that my **WindowState** was defaulted to *Maximized* from the start. This [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350240/wpf-binding-margin-thickness-left-and-top-property) helped me understand that too. I solved my issue by binding my **WindowState** and defaulting it to *Normal*. I then set the new **Left** value and bind it to the property, and finally I changed my **WindowState** to *Maximized*.

```
//setting up the dashboard window position, first
//the WindowState has to be set to Normal
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

//second, we get the offset value based on the configuration settings
ScreenOffset = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width + defaultOffset;

//third, we set the desired WindowState to Maximized
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Now my window appears in its desired location. Thank you again.